# XmlSerializer Attribute not available for certain Items

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Trying to Serialize item when certain attributes are sometime available and sometimes do not. Issue was mistakenly I put VerifyMinAmount as bool due to this XmlDeserialize was throwing exception. Now its fixed

```
<items>
    <item idimagelogo="892"  verifyamount="True" receipt="02" >
    </item>
    <item idimagelogo="893"  Receipt="02" >
    </item>
    <item idimagelogo="893"  verifyamount="True" >
    </item>
</items>
```

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "idimagelogo")]
    public string idimagelogo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "verifyamount")]
    public string VerifyMinAmount { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "receipt")]
    public string Receipt { get; set; }
}

public static T XmlDeserialize<T>(XNode data,string rootAttribute = "") where T : class, new()
{
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }

    XmlSerializer ser=null;
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rootAttribute))
        ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
    else
        ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute(rootAttribute));

    return (T) ser.Deserialize(data.CreateReader());
}
```

Comment: Kindly advise how to Serialize item, when verifyamount and Receipt can be present or null

Comment: @JamesZ trying to serialize items using C# but problem is either Attribute Receipt or verifyamount is not present in Item. Could you please advise how to XmlSerializer using C#

Comment: @mjwills will create another question with complete minimum, Complete and Verifiable example